# After css and js minified why my wordpress site is slow?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, minify

After minified all css and js why my wordpress site is slow? I use Ipage hosting. I test my site in http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights It show desktop mode 83/100. http://infotech-24.com This is my site. My wordpress theme size 2.20MB. no plugins i use
In .htaccess file I use this code `DirectoryIndex index.php`

### EXPIRES CACHING ##

`<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>`

### EXPIRES CACHING

## compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript`

Please help me

Comment: Why do you have `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,400italic,700" >` declared 3 times?

Comment: Your webserver is slow to respond. The issue isn't getting the resources to the client, it's the time taken for the server to start handing them out. My guess is that your shared or VPS hosting is over subscribed. Also, enabling gzip compression will reduce the payload size by about two thirds, but it'll increase CPU resource usage and I don't think you've much available.

Comment: I use this theme http://themes.muffingroup.com/pindol How I remove fonts

Comment: Also, instead calling two fonts with two links, you can do it with one link: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,400italic,700|Patua+One" >

Answer (score 1):

Chrome's developer toolbar shows 2.05s second latency, which is the time from the browser requesting the document to the a response being returned by the web server. Everything else only takes ~1.5 second to load, bringing the total load time to 3.5s.

That 2 second latency occurs before any JS, CSS or image dependencies begin loading. In other words, it takes 2 seconds for your server to prepare the HTML document. That's where I would look to make speed improvements.

Since this is a WordPress site there are database requests being made every time a page is rendered, which is likely where the slowdown is occurring. The first thing I would do to speed up a WordPress site is install a caching plugin such as W3 Total Cache. The default W3TC settings are usually fine - just turn Page Caching and Database Caching on. (And remember that caching is bypassed if you are logged into WordPress).

I recently worked a WP site where the uncached DOM load time (i.e. latency) was 10 seconds, and with caching it was 500ms, so there are some big gains to be made.

Answer (score 0):

That is not particularly bad, it took me 2 - 3 seconds to load. Also, consider the fact that Google only scores 91/100. 83/100 is somewhat acceptable.

You can however consider fixing (as per test results):

- Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content
- Reduce server response time
- Optimize images
- Minify JavaScript